# Computational complexity - a recurrence relation

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

How do I  distinguish the $2$ cases in the snippet below on the minus $4$th line ?
I.e. I do not follow the last line which says: **considering separately the case 
$k<n/2$ and the case $k\geq n/2$.**
How do I compute $$cn+\frac{10c}{n}(\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{kn}{2}-\frac{k^2}{2.5}) \leq cn+\frac{10c}{n}\frac{9n^2}{10}$$ by distinguishing the two cases ??

Also I would like to understand what it means in the Claim $7.4$ this sentence:

> Let $T(n) \text{ be the maximum of } T(k,a_1,\ldots,a_n) \text { over all $n$ length inputs }.$

I.e. what are $n$ length inputs $T(k,a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ - what is the length of $k$, say, in $T(k,a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mention the length of $k$, note that we're really after the $k$th element in an *unsorted* sequence.  The elements are labelled as $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$, etc. up to $a_n$.  The algorithm picks a random index in the set, more specifically the $i$th element $a_i$, and counts the number of elements less than it.  Then it either finishes, or branches recursively.

Now, in the analysis, we consider all possible running times of the algorithm, and label them $T(k, a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$.  Then, $T(n)$ is defined as the maximum running time out of all of these times, for length $n$.

I believe what the author intends, when they mention about considering the two cases seperately, is to consider replacing $k$ by $n/2$, which works in both cases:

$$cn + \frac{10c}{n} \left( \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{kn}{2} - \frac{k^2}{2.5} \right) = $$
$$cn + \frac{10c}{n} \left( \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{(n/2)n}{2} - \frac{(n/2)^2}{2.5} \right) = $$
$$cn + \frac{10c}{n} \left( \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{(n)^2}{10} \right) < $$
$$cn + \frac{10c}{n}\frac{65n^2}{100}$$

I'm not sure I quite catch the reference that the author is considering, but the simple math checks out by replacing $k$ by $n/2$, which is the worst case in both cases.

Comment: You seem to understand what I need to know. So please **what** is the length of $k$ ?

Comment: $k$ stands for the $k$th smallest element.  In other words, if we have a set $\{5,4,7,2,6\}$ and $k=3$, then that means that we're looking for the $3$rd smallest element, which is $5$.  If $k=2$, then the $2$nd smallest element is $4$, and so on.

Comment: @user122424: In other words, $k$ is given as part of the problem description.  We want to find the $k$th element in a set $\{a_1 = 5, a_2 = 4, a_3 = 7, a_4 = 2, a_5 = 6\}$, for example.   The set and $k$ are given as part of the problem.  In this case, $n=5$ is also given, and is the total elements in the set, which is $5$.

Comment: So in your example the length of $k=3$ is $3$, right ?

Comment: @user122424:  I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at...  $k$ is actually a count.  $k$ determines which number in the set that we want, and is given as part of the problem.  When $k$ is given as $3$, then the algorithm finds the third smallest element in the set, which in the set $\{ 5, 4, 7, 2, 6 \}$ is $5$.  I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: From the beginning I wanted to understand what "over all length $n$ inputs" refers to . I understand what you write, but I'm missing that detail yet. The $k$ there is also an *input* **so** it must have **length** and probably this length must be $n$.

Comment: They say in claim $7.4$: "let $T(n)$ be the maximum of $T(k,a_1,...,a_n)$ over all $n$ length inputs" and in the first sentence "for every input $k,a_1,...,a_n$."

Comment: The _length_ is $n$.  In other words, the input to the problem is a list $(a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots a_n)$, which of course has $n$ values in it, hence _length_ $n$, and another number $k$.  We include $k$ because we're looking for the $k$th smallest input from the list.  That is the problem.

Comment: OK. But then we shall look at all **$n+1$** (and not $n$) length inputs *if we include $k$* as an input to $T$, right ?

Comment: Yeah, I think technically we're looking at length $n+1$ inputs.  They probably should have tried to clarify that better.

Comment: But still, there are **infinitely** many $(n+1)$ sequences $k,a_1,...,a_n$; why the max of them - $T(n)$ - is attained ??

Comment: You know T(n) is defined to be the time that the algorithm takes to process the list $(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$, if it's looking for the $k$th smallest element.  The algorithm is randomized, so we just look for the absolute worst performance that we can possibly get...  That is $T(k,a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n)$.  And it can't be worse than $O(n)$, no matter what random values it uses.

Comment: I guess I should add that that's what the analysis does... We try to find $T(...)$ in the worst case.